# Unexplainable error while writing data into Excel file in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

My DFT fetches data from an SP. It is followed by a conditional split to split dataset into 5 parts based on a column value. The sub-datasets are then written into an excel file. All 5 outputs write into the same excel file, But different tabs. I have explicitly mentioned the Column range and starting row for the data to be written. Data load into the Excel file fails with the following error.

**[EXC DST EAC TREND HPS [1379]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
[EXC DST EAC TREND HPS [1379]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Excel Destination Input" (1390)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Excel Destination Input" (1390)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "EXC DST EAC TREND HPS" (1379) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Excel Destination Input" (1390). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.**

The most frustrating part is that the Excel destinations fail at random. Lets name them as A,B,C,D and E. During 1st run A will fail and the rest will write data successfully. During the 2nd run, A will succeed but C and E will fail and so on. 
Every time the Excel Dest fails, data is still written in that particular tab. But I can see some blank rows in the dataset. I added a data viewer before each Excel Dest and the data looks correct. There are no blank rows either. number of rows per data set are fixed (18).
I am using a template every time which has only Column headers.
4 columns have datatype of nvarchar with max data length of around 50. 12 columns are Numeric(38,2).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Gaz

Answer (score 0):

Reorganize the package so that the writes will occur sequentially.   The error you are seeing is the result of concurrency issues.   You can't write to the same file in 5 different places at once.  You have to do let each write finish before the next one starts.